# How can I make a UI element editable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'll be glad if you can help me on an the following issue. I have a list of categories which is look like this:

[image]

I need that each time I click on a category block, it will be transformed
into textbox where the user can input his category. Once the user is out of the textbox, the input is kept within the block. Here's the code so far for the categories:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="dd" id="nestable">
        <ol class="dd-list" id="category-list">
            <li class="dd-item" data-id="3">
                <div class="dd-handle">
                    <span>Item 3</span>
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.dd {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
/*    list-style: none;*/
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.dd-list {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: decimal;
/*    list-style: none;*/
}

.dd-item, .dd-empty, .dd-placeholder {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 20px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.dd-handle {
    display: block;
    height: 34px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background: white;
    /*    background: #F6F6F6;*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#category-list").on( "click", ".close", function( event ) {
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();
   });  

});
```

The link for jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hppb1cLq/1/

Can you please show me how to do it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This might help you to get started. *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330309/turning-a-div-into-a-input-element-and-save-data-into-a-database?answertab=active#tab-top*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `replaceWith()` method on click of the `span` to insert an `input` in its place, and also on blur of the `input` to return the `span`. Something like this:

```
$("#category-list").on("click", ".close", function(e) {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
}).on('click', 'span', function() {
    var $input = $('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).text().trim() + '" />');
    $(this).replaceWith($input);
    $input.select();
}).on('blur', 'input', function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<span>' + $(this).val() + '</span>');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/hppb1cLq/2/)

Comment: Rory, thanks a lot! But I see that the editbox of the input goes down. How can I set that it will be exactly fit on the div block of the li item ?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but you can change all the settings of the input as required through CSS

Answer (score 2):

You can use `contentEditable="true"` attribute, like:

https://jsfiddle.net/42bvqnj9/

More information at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable

Comment: Eduardo, thanks a lot! but how can I make this edit along the div block of the li item ?